# Ошибка с переменной global?

Tags: python

Здравствуйте! 
Пишу:

```
global a
def a():
   a = 1;
def b():
   print b;
```

Пишет что переменная a не определенна
Что это?

Comment: На глобальном уровне имя "a" уже связано с функцией `a` (и имя "b" тоже связано с соответствующей функцией). Если вам все-таки удастся внутри функции `a` заменить значение глобальной переменной `a` на 1, то вы больше не сможете вызвать функцию `a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Несколько советов:

- Не используйте глобальные переменные. Если нужно чтобы функция что-то поменяла во "внешнем мире", лучше использовать возвращаемое ей значение. Если функция должна что-то получать из внешнего мира - для этого есть аргументы функции (исключение - "константы", т.е. глобальные переменные, которые "никогда" не меняются, например число pi). Если есть набор глобальных переменных, и набор работающих с этими переменными функций - стоит задуматься над тем, чтобы обернуть все это хозяйство в класс.
- Давайте переменным и функциям разные имена
- Не используйте точку с запятой в конце строки

По поводу `global` - он должен быть внутри функции. Рабочий пример кода:

```
def func():
    global a
    a = 1

func()

print(a)  # Вывод: 1
```

Пример с возвращаемым значением (лучше делать так):

```
def func():
    return 1

a = func()

print(a)  # Вывод: 1
```