# Использование global в Python

Tags: python, python-faq

Здравствуйте, знакомлюсь с python и после c++ категорически не понимаю  принцип использования global переменных. Если у переменной, находящейся в def указать  global то можно ли её значение использовать вне этой функции, у меня точно не получается. Может просто потому что я новичок и очевидные вещи для меня еще слишком сложны.

```
def check():
    global urokb_in
    urokb_in = 1
    with open('users.txt', 'r') as f:
        line = f.readline()
        f.close()
    with open('progress.txt', 'r') as k:
        while True:
            global uroka_in
            lines = k.readline()
            if line == lines.rstrip():
                uroka_in = int(k.readline().rstrip())
                urokb_in = uroka_in + 1
                uroka_str = str(uroka_in)
                urokb_str = str(urokb_in)
                lines.replace(uroka_str, urokb_str)
                k.close()
                break
            if not lines:
                k.close()
                urokb_in = 1
                with open('progress.txt', 'a') as j:
                    j.write(line)
                    j.write('\n')
                    j.write(str(urokb_in))
                    j.write('\n')
                    j.close()
                    break
    if urokb_in == 1:
       educate__scr = PhotoImage(file='e_scr_1.png')
       educate_label = Label(root, image=educate__scr)
       educate_label.place(x=0, y=0)
```

Более опытные кодеры подскажите как исправить.
SyntaxError: name 'urokb_in' is used prior to global declaration

Comment: `global uroka_in` должно быть внутри функции (сразу после `def`, только один раз).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка с переменной global?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/644002/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-global)

Comment: @insolor тогда я не могу использовать значение urokb_in в условии вне функции

Comment: Можете. У вас просто функция не вызывается, насколько я понимаю. Нужно сначала вызвать функцию, а потом уже проверять условие.

Comment: @insolor def chek вызывается ранее по нажатию на кнопку. И при выходе из функции я хочу получить значение из urokb_in

Comment: Тогда задавайте какое-то значение переменной заранее, как в ответе Xyanight, например `uroka_in = None`, потом в условии проверяйте, если все еще `uroka_in == None` значит функция не вызывалась.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Если не указать global или nonlocal, то [`x =` внутри функции создаёт локальную переменную](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765707/23044).

Если вы хотите новую глобальную переменную создать/или переопределить старую *внутри функции* (не на глобальном уровне), то можно global использовать. Это может быть полезно при работе с `multiprocessing` модулем, чтобы унаследовать желаемые глобальные переменные от родительского процесса:

```
def init(shared_arr_):
    global shared_arr
    shared_arr = shared_arr_ # must be inherited, not passed as an argument
```

[Полный пример кода](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7908612/4279).

Если вы хотите просто использовать существующую глобальную переменную, не переопределяя её, то global не нужен (иначе к примеру, пришлось бы в каждой функции каждый используемый модуль, каждую глобальную функцию объявлять global).

> я новичок и очевидные вещи для меня еще слишком сложны

Для новичков: *не переопределяйте глобальные переменные вообще*, то есть избегайте `global`. Считайте каждое появление global в коде ошибкой, если нет особых причин для использования этой конструкции (как в примере с `multiprocessing`). Если не получается избавится от global, то создайте минимальный пример кода и задайте отдельный вопрос: "как избавиться от global, делая X"

Comment: как локально присвоить глобальной переменной значение? у меня создавалась локальная переменная с тем же именем. ну кроме `nonlocal` =)

Comment: @eri посмотрите на `shared_arr` в примере кода выше. Какое поведение вы ожидали и что вместо этого происходит?

Answer (score 7):

Инструкция `global` используется там где необходимо явно указать на то, что следует использовать объект из глобальной области видимости (namespace модуля или словарь globals) и отменяет стандартный механизм поиска для переменной (`LEGB`), дополнительно к этому даёт возможность изменения объекта не в своей области видимости. требует дисциплины в общем то, так как если до объявления `global a` во вложенной области видимости имени `а` не было в OВ `globals()` она будет создана при первой операции присваивания и не пропадёт при завершении работы (к примеру функции).

```
dir()
# ['__builtins__']

def foo():
    global a
    a = 22
    pass

dir()
# ['__builtins__', 'foo']

# foo необходимо вызвать.

foo()

dir()
# ['__builtins__', 'a', 'foo']

a
# 22

# а теперь живет в globals()

def foo1():
    print(a)

foo1()
# 22

# по правилу LEGB имя а было найдено в globals()

def foo2():
    a += 4
    pass

foo2()
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
#   File "<input>", line 2, in foo2
# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment

# запрещено изменение переменных не в своей области видимости для этого
# требуется сначала указать что нужно изменить именно a из globals()

def foo3():
    global a
    a += 4

foo3()
a
# 26
```

Comment: Подскажите как мне перехватить urokb_in после if not lines и после if line == lines.rstrip():

Answer (score 4):

Указывать глобальную переменную нужно непосредственно в теле функции в самом начале, например:

```
x = 1

def set_value():
    global x

    x = 2


print(x)
>>> 1

set_value()

print(x)
>>> 2
```

Answer (score -1):

В строке после While True: не нужно еще раз определять global.
Переменная уже определена ранее.