# Не отображается изображение в Label

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-faq

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Разрабатываю своё первое оконное приложение, и вот столкнулся с проблемой. Я вызываю функцию с параметром и в зависимости от параметра в Label должно выводиться разное изображение. Но вместо этого просто серый экран, изображения на кнопке тоже нет, но свою функцию кнопка исправно выполняет. Что с этим делать ума не приложу раньше все работало нормально. Заранее спасибо

```
from tkinter import *


def eclick(event):
   root.destroy()

def edscr():

    e_sc_1 = PhotoImage(file='e_scr_1.png')
    e_scr_1 = Label(root, image=e_sc_1)
    e_scr_1.place(x=0, y=0)

    e_but = PhotoImage(file='but_e.png')
    but_e = Button(root, width=477, height=16, image=e_but)
    but_e.place(x=130, y=350)
    but_e.bind('<Button-1>', eclick)


root = Tk()
edscr()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ссылку на изображение следует сохранять (к примеру, [как атрибут экземпляра: `self._photo_image` -- функцию в метод превратите](https://gist.github.com/zed/8b05c3ea0302f0e2c14c)). Для вопроса попробуйте минимальный пример кода с нуля создать (достаточно одного изображения) [mcve]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как прокомментировал [@jfs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/23044/jfs) [*"ссылку на изображение следует сохранять"*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767818/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-label-python3-tkinter#comment1195447_767818) по этому в данном ответе весь объект `Tk` помещен в `class` пример кода, а само изображение помещено в переменную `self.image` т.е. вы присваиваете изображение в блок класса:

```
import tkinter


class Ex(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='2.gif')
        label = tkinter.Label(self, image=self.image)
        label.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Ex()
    main.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Для того чтобы использовать другие виды расширения используйте библиотеку `PIL` пример:

```
import tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Ex(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        pil_image = Image.open("2.jpg")
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)
        image_sprite = tkinter.Label(self, image=self.image)
        image_sprite.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Ex()
    main.mainloop()
```

### [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же можно поместить изображение в [глобальную переменную](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767818/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-label-python3-tkinter/767829?noredirect=1#comment1195558_767829) в функции, но лучше через [`class`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/767734/255866)

```
import tkinter


def main():
    global image
    image = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='2.gif')
    label = tkinter.Label(root, image=image)
    label.pack()


root = tkinter.Tk()
main()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Самое странное в том что и без PIL  код хорошо обрабатывал png изображения и на функции поломался

Comment: про расширения здесь ни к чему говорить (это red herring).¶ Без явной необходимости наследование лучше не использовать (композицию обычно более предпочтительна). Дополнительно, вы рискуете случайно переопределить унаследованные от Tk атрибуты здесь.

Comment: @андрейгривкин по завершению выполнения функции, картинка удаляется в CPython, так  как нет больше ссылок на неё (локальная переменная не переживает вызов функции). Чтобы убедится, можно для проверки код из edscr() функции на глобальный уровень вынести (картинка не удаляется в этом случае). В общем случае, класс создайте, чтобы в глобальном пространстве имён не мусорить.