# При открытии файла не выводится изображение на canvas. Как исправить?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Проецирование изображение на Canvas в Tkinter:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import *
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageTk
root = Tk()
root.geometry('900x600')
im16 = PhotoImage(file='многоугольник.gif')
canv = Canvas(root, bg='white', width='1000', height='1000')
canv.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=300)
def r():
    l = askopenfilename()
    z = Image.open(l)
    img30 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(z)
    canv.create_image(50, 10, image=img30, anchor=NW)
    but24 = Button(root, image=im16, command=r)
    but24.grid(row=0, column=10)
```

При открытии файла не выводится изображение на `canvas`. Как исправить?

Answer (score 2):

У вас само изображение [сохранялась 
в локальную переменную](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767818/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-label-python3-tkinter/767829#767829) по этому,  могло не отображаться.
А исправленный код программы выглядит таким образом:

```
import tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk 
import tkinter.filedialog


class Ex(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(self, bg='white', width='400', height='400')
        self.canvas.pack()
        button = tkinter.Button(self, text='Нажми', command=self.open_image)
        button.pack()

    def open_image(self):
        directory = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()
        pil_image = Image.open(directory)
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)
        self.canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=self.image)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Ex()
    main.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в коде в вопросе `from PIL import Image` последним идёт, поэтому `Image.open` должно работать. Проблема с кодом вероятно в том, что img30 это локальная переменная (поэтому соответствующее изображение не переживает окончание вызова r() функции (вызов не показан, поэтому  ещё одна причина в том, что r не вызвана). Вы уже на похожий вопрос отвечали недавно?

Comment: @jfs Да, только он был связан с `Label` [Не отображается изображение в Label Python3 (Tkinter)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767818/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-label-python3-tkinter/767829#767829)