# Не отображается изображение на canvas в tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
def save():
    global im64
    l = askopenfilename()
    im111 = Image.open(l)
    im64 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im111)
canv.create_image(50, 10, image=im64, anchor=NW)
but24 = Button(root, image=im16, command=im64)
```

Не отображается изображение на `canvas`

Comment: Дубликат вопроса [Проецирование изображение на Canvas в Tkinter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/783199/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-canvas-%d0%b2-tkinter/783202#783202)

Comment: @Twiss это одногруппница, возможно )