# Можно ли размещать два изображения в окне Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Мне хотелось бы узнать можно ли разместить два изображения на одном окне tkinter, я уже пробовал но у меня размещалось только одно изображение.
Если можно то можете мне сделать пример кода?

Пример кода:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()
root.geometry('700x700')
root.title("Name")

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Name.jpg"))           
panel = Label(root, image = img)                                                   
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "no")   

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос свой код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно создать второй `Label` для помещения в него `image`. [Почему код построен именно так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767818/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-label-python3-tkinter/767829#767829)

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('700x700')
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("1.png"))
        panel = tk.Label(self, image=self.img).pack()
        button = tk.Button(self, text='Нажми', command=self.func).pack()

    def func(self):
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()))
        tk.Label(self, image=self.image).pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Main()
    main.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: существенный неочевидный момент, что следует явно сохранять ссылки на все отображаемые картинки (`self.img`, `self.image` в этом случае)

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы в строку разместить картинки:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Usage: show-images [<images>...]"""
import sys
from tkinter import Tk  # PhotoImage # gif, ppn,pnm
from tkinter.ttk import Label
from PIL import ImageTk, Image  # bmp, png, jpeg, tiff

root = Tk()
images = []
for i, filename in enumerate(sys.argv[1:]):
    label = Label()
    # have to keep references to images
    images.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(filename)))
    label['image'] = images[-1]
    label.grid(row=0, column=i)
root.mainloop()
```

Пример:

```
$ show-images ~/Pictures/SO/profile-pic*
```

[image: tkinter two pictures]