# как в listbox использовать curselection

Tags: python, tkinter

По нажатию на один из пунктов listbox должна появится фотография но ничего не происходит.  `if (event.widget.curselection())==0:` ноль это строка listbox если что.

```
def listbox():
    def Get(event):
        if (event.widget.curselection())==0:
            image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="0.png")
            text=Label(root, image = image)

    top=Toplevel(root)
    listbox=Listbox(top,width=20)

    listbox.insert(END,'image 0','image 1','image 2','image 3','image 4','image 5',
         'image 6','image 7','image 8','image 9')

    listbox.pack()
    listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>",Get) 

king=Menu(root)
root.config(menu=king)
view= Menu(king,tearoff = 0)
view.add_command(label='Background',command=listbox)
king.add_cascade(label="View",menu=view)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот ваше решение проблемы:

```
from tkinter import*

def listbox():
    def image_get(list_):
        global image_1
        if int(list_.curselection()[0]) == 0:
            image_1 = PhotoImage(file="./1.png")
            lab = Label(root, bg="white", image = image_1)
            lab.place(x=10, y=10, width=100, height=100)

    top = Toplevel(root)
    list_ = Listbox(top,width=20)

    list_.insert(END,'image 0','image 1','image 2','image 3','image 4','image 5', 'image 6','image 7','image 8','image 9')
    list_.pack()
    list_.bind("<Double-1>", lambda event: image_get(list_) or top.destroy())


root = Tk()

king = Menu(root, postcommand=lambda: listbox())
root.config(menu=king)
view = Menu(king,tearoff = 0)
#view.add_command(label='Background',command=None)
king.add_cascade(label="View",menu=view)

root.mainloop()
```

Заметьте, что я сделал глобальную переменную `image_1`, т.к из моей практики `PhotoImage` нужно делать общей переменной. По этому, лучше импортировать все фотографии в начале после `import` модулей.

---

Класс `Menu` имеет параметр `postcommand` [(Вот документация)](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/menu.html), которой мы передаем функцию которую нам нужно вызвать при нажатии на пункт `Menu`

---

PS. [Все классы и их параметры по модулю Tkinter](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html)

Comment: Я бы еще сделал бы защиту от создания нескольких окон

Comment: Вместо `place` можно другие методы использовать

Answer (score 1):

1. Когда вы вызываете функцию `Get` при нажатие на селекцию у вас выводится кортеж (вы можете это легко проверить просто вывести результат `print(event.widget.curselection())`)
   Для того чтобы решить данную проблему достаточно просто вызвать его первое значение `event.widget.curselection()[0]`.
2. Дальше у вас косяк в том что вы не упаковываете `Label` у вас он просто создается, но не отображается.
3. И мало важный, но скорее всего будущий косяк в отображении изображения, но про него вы можете прочитать вот здесь [Не отображается изображение в Label Python3 (Tkinter)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/767829/255866).

---

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk


class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        button = tk.Button(self, text='Нажми', command=self.func).pack()

    def func(self):
        top = tk.Toplevel(self)
        listbox = tk.Listbox(top, width=20)

        listbox.insert(tk.END, 'image 0', 'image 1', 'image 2', 'image 3', 'image 4', 'image 5',
                       'image 6', 'image 7', 'image 8', 'image 9')

        listbox.pack()
        listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.image_get)

    def image_get(self, event):
        if event.widget.curselection()[0] == 0:
            self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="1.gif")
            text = tk.Label(self, image=self.image).pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main().mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.s. написание скобок в данном `(event.widget.curselection())` случае ничего особенного не делает

Comment: Это очень помогло, но что делать если listbox вызывается не кнопкой, а пунктом меню, как тогда исправить код

Comment: @A.Kross пример кода добавьте, а то не совсем понятно что вы хотите

Comment: Вот пример кода, по нажатию на пункт меню background должен вызваться listbox

Comment: @A.Kross вам нужно именно чтобы вызывался `top` после нажатие на руки из меню. Если да то точно так же как я. Вам привел пример в ответе

Comment: да только у вас вызывается после нажатия на кнопку, а мне надо чтобы это осуществлялось после нажатия на пункт меню. Не подскажите как надо изменить код

Comment: @A.Kross ну у вас же тоже с через `command` просто замените на функцию как в моем варианте на `command=self.func`. я не вижу здесь проблемы