# Не выводится картинка python tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, tkinter

Пытаюсь сделать простенькую игру на python. Для простоты делаю "framework" чтобы было легче сделать игру и возможно использовать это в будущем. При попытке написать функцию для вывода картинки в canvas возникает непонятная мне проблема:
если писать код без класса, код идентичный функции addImage, то все работает без проблем, но когда пытаюсь использовать функцию, то выводится только линия(она существует только для теста)

```
from tkinter import *

rootW, rootH = 1000, 1000

class Fw:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry('1000x1000')
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root,width=1000,height=1000)
        self.canvas.pack()
    def addImage(self, file):
        image = PhotoImage(file=file)
        self.canvas.create_image(300, 300, image=image) #картинки нет
        self.canvas.create_line(0, 0, 1000, 1000) #линия есть
    def move(self, target, x, y):
        self.canvas.move(target, x, y)
    def mainLoop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

fwk = Fw()
fwk.addImage("Player.png")


fwk.mainLoop()
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не отображается изображение в Label Python3 (Tkinter)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767818/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-label-python3-tkinter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Так попробуйте**

```
from tkinter import *

rootW, rootH = 1000, 1000
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Fw:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry('1000x1000')
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root,width=1000,height=1000)
        self.canvas.pack()
    def addImage(self, file):
        self.img = Image.open(file)
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
        self.canvas.create_image(300, 300, image=self.image) #картинки нет
        self.canvas.create_line(0, 0, 1000, 1000) #линия есть
    def move(self, target, x, y):
        self.canvas.move(target, x, y)
    def mainLoop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

fwk = Fw()
fwk.addImage("Player.png")


fwk.mainLoop()
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.