# Добавление картинки в TkInter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Я пытаюсь добавить картинку в TkInter, я пробовал много вариантов:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

img = Label(root, image=PhotoImage(file='path'))
img2 = Button(root, image=PhotoImage(file='path'))
# img3 = Image()    я не знаю атрибутов к этому объекту, в интернете ничего нету

img.grid()
img2.grid(column=1)
# img3.grid(column=2
```

У меня или не отображается (когда-как), или выдаётся ошибка.
Есть способ добавить картинку без установки других библиотек (типа `PIL`)?

Comment: Дубликат: [Не отображается изображение в Label](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/767818). Вкратце: объект PhotoImage нужно сохранить в какую-то переменную, иначе он будет автоматически удален сборщиком мусора, который посчитает, что после передачи в Label он уже не нужен.

Comment: `# img3 = Image()    я не знаю атрибутов к этому объекту, в интернете ничего нету` - в tkinter нет специального виджета Image, есть базовый класс Image, потомком которого является PhotoImage, но для использования его напрямую он фактически не предназначен.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала нужно создать `canvas` (это стандартный метод tkinter):

```
canvas = Canvas(gui, bg = 'white', height = 100, width = 100)
canvas.pack()
```

`width` и `height` настраивай по размерам своего окна tkinter.

Затем создать фото через `PhotoImage`:

```
test = PhotoImage(file='test1.png')
```

Потом:

```
testImg = canvas.create_image(100,190, anchor = NW, image = test)
```

По координатам ориентируйся сам.

В итоге получится так:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x700')
canvas = Canvas(root, bg = 'white', height = 100, width = 100)
canvas.pack()
test = PhotoImage(file='test1.png')
testImg = canvas.create_image(100,190, anchor = NW, image = test)
```