# Canvas в дочернем окне, Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Не отрисовывается Canvas в дочернем окне, что делать?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import ImageTk
from tkinter import ttk
import settings
 
# Основное окно
 
root = Tk()
root.title("Рандомайзер")   # Название окна
root.geometry("800x500+150+200") # Размер окна
root.iconbitmap(settings.ICON) # Иконка окна
root.resizable(width=False, height=False) # Неизменяемость размера окна
 
C = Canvas(bg="blue", height=250, width=300) 
filename = PhotoImage(file=settings.BACKGROUND) # Фон окна
background_label = Label(image=filename)    
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1) 
 
fg = '#f0e6e8'  # Мягкий белый цвет     
bg = '#BA112C'  # Цвет фона
 
 
# Окно настроек
def create_window():
    second_window = Toplevel()     
    second_window.title("Настройки")     
    second_window.geometry("400x250+200+400") # Размер окна
    second_window.iconbitmap(settings.ICON_SETTINGS) # Иконка окна
    second_window.resizable(width=False, height=False) # Неизменяемость размера окна
    bg_settings_window = settings.BACKGROUND2
    C = Canvas(bg="blue", height=250, width=300) 
    photo = PhotoImage(file=bg_settings_window) # Фон окна
    bl = Label(image=photo)    
    bl.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1) 
    # Button, Entry, Labels (window_settings)
 
    style = ttk.Style()
    style.configure("TRadiobutton", background="#BA112C", foreground='white')
 
    ttk.Radiobutton(second_window, value=1, style="TRadiobutton").pack()
 
    second_window.mainloop()
 
 
# Logic window 1
 
 
# Button, Label, Entry 
 
# Все картинки
 
images = {
    'btn_generate': PhotoImage(file=settings.BTN_GENERATE),
    'btn_icon': PhotoImage(file=settings.BTN_ICON_SETTINGS),
}
 
style = ttk.Style()
 
style.configure("TRadiobutton", background=bg, foreground='white')
style.configure("TButton", background=bg, foreground="#BA112C", font="HelveticaNeueCyr 17 bold", image=images['btn_generate'])
 
main_entry = ttk.Entry(root, width=60, font="Arial 10 bold")
main_entry.place(x=190, y=150, height=55)
 
ttk.Radiobutton(root, text="Выбрать из списка", value=1, style="TRadiobutton").place(x=30, y=440)
ttk.Radiobutton(root, text="Случайное число", value=2, style="TRadiobutton").place(x=200, y=440)
ttk.Radiobutton(root, text="Случайный пароль", value=3, style="TRadiobutton").place(x=200, y=390)
ttk.Radiobutton(root, text="Перемешать слова", value=4, style="TRadiobutton").place(x=30, y=390)
 
ttk.Button(root, text="Сгенерировать", style="TButton").place(x=283, y=235)
Button(root, image=images['btn_icon'], background=bg, command=create_window).place(x=730, y=15)
 
root.mainloop()`введите сюда код`
```

Comment: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/BrzIbi6kymsq0g ссылка на проект

Comment: Вся информация для вопроса должна быть в самом вопросе, а не на pastebin, яндекс диске и т.д.

Comment: как мне скинуть проект, если он у меня не особо маленький?

Comment: там фоны и прочие изображения, по которым у меня как раз вопрос. Спасибо, что подсказали, что надо руками, а то я ногами уже 5 часов старался ниче не получилось ;)

Comment: Пожалуйста. Вот здесь ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/767818/1365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы всё правильно начали делать - сохранять `PhotoImage` в словарь. Но, почему-то, не стали делать это для картинок фона.
Плюс `Label` с фоном для второго окна забыли сделать его наследником.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import ImageTk
from tkinter import ttk
import settings

# Основное окно

root = Tk()

# Все картинки
images = {
    'btn_generate'  : PhotoImage(file=settings.BTN_GENERATE),
    'btn_icon'      : PhotoImage(file=settings.BTN_ICON_SETTINGS),
    "bg_root"       : PhotoImage(file=settings.BACKGROUND),
    "bg_settings"   : PhotoImage(file=settings.BACKGROUND2)
}

root.title("Рандомайзер")   # Название окна
root.geometry("800x500+150+200") # Размер окна
root.iconbitmap(settings.ICON) # Иконка окна
root.resizable(width=False, height=False) # Неизменяемость размера окна

background_label = Label(image=images["bg_root"])    
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1) 

fg = '#f0e6e8'  # Мягкий белый цвет     
bg = '#BA112C'  # Цвет фона


# Окно настроек
def create_window():
    second_window = Toplevel()     
    second_window.title("Настройки")     
    second_window.geometry("400x250+200+400") # Размер окна
    second_window.iconbitmap(settings.ICON_SETTINGS) # Иконка окна
    second_window.resizable(width=False, height=False) # Неизменяемость размера окна
    bl = Label(second_window, image=images["bg_settings"])    
    bl.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1) 
    # Button, Entry, Labels (window_settings)

    style = ttk.Style()
    style.configure("TRadiobutton", background="#BA112C", foreground='white')

    ttk.Radiobutton(second_window, value=1, style="TRadiobutton").pack()



# Logic window 1


# Button, Label, Entry 

style = ttk.Style()

style.configure("TRadiobutton", background=bg, foreground='white')
style.configure("TButton", background=bg, foreground="#BA112C", font="HelveticaNeueCyr 17 bold", image=images['btn_generate'])

main_entry = ttk.Entry(root, width=60, font="Arial 10 bold")
main_entry.place(x=190, y=150, height=55)

ttk.Radiobutton(root, text="Выбрать из списка", value=1, style="TRadiobutton").place(x=30, y=440)
ttk.Radiobutton(root, text="Случайное число", value=2, style="TRadiobutton").place(x=200, y=440)
ttk.Radiobutton(root, text="Случайный пароль", value=3, style="TRadiobutton").place(x=200, y=390)
ttk.Radiobutton(root, text="Перемешать слова", value=4, style="TRadiobutton").place(x=30, y=390)

ttk.Button(root, text="Сгенерировать", style="TButton").place(x=283, y=235)
Button(root, image=images['btn_icon'], background=bg, command=create_window).place(x=730, y=15)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: -]

Comment: ВЫ ПРОСТО БОГ! Извиняюсь, если вы атеист, но по-другому описать нельзя) СПАСИБО ВАМ ОГРОМНЕЙШЕЕ!!!!