# У меня не получается вывести картинку в окно tkinter. Программа ошибку не показывает

Tags: python, изображения, tkinter

У меня не получается вывести картинку в окно tkinter. Программа ошибку не показывает.

```
def my_buttonf():
    window = Tk()
    window.title('Logic quiz')
    window.geometry('400x300')
    label = Label(window, text='''

    Спасибо за отзыв! ''', font="Arial 24", fg='#316879')
    label.pack()

    img = PhotoImage("download.png")
    b = Label(image=img)
    b.img = "download.png"
    b.pack()

    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Связанный вопрос (не дубликат): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/767818/1365

Answer (score 2):

Так как класс `PhotoImage` имеет такой конструктор:

```
class PhotoImage(Image):
    """Widget which can display images in PGM, PPM, GIF, PNG format."""

    def __init__(self, name=None, cnf={}, master=None, **kw):
        """Create an image with NAME.

        Valid resource names: data, format, file, gamma, height, palette,
        width."""
        Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
```

Вам необходимо использовать имееннованный параметр `file`

```
  img = PhotoImage(file = "download.png")
```

В качестве подтверждения работы кода

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: но держать все приложение tkinter в функции - это благоприятная почва для багов и ошибок

Comment: этот код я не писал, я лишь привел воспроизводимый пример оригинального кода и причину, которая указана в исходниках класа **Valid resource names: data, format, file, gamma, height, palette,
        width.**

Comment: @DaniilLoban,  у меня почему-то все еще выводится только текст.

Comment: сложно сказать в чем дело, то что я заметил я исправил.

Comment: @FotonPC, это только одна функция из всего кода. Вся программа не внутри функции.

Answer (score -1):

Необходимо `file=` указывать. И чтобы переменная с изображением не удалялась сборщиком мусора (я просто убрал функцию).

```
from tkinter import *


window = Tk()
window.title('Logic quiz')
window.geometry('400x300')
label = Label(window, text='''

Спасибо за отзыв! ''', font="Arial 24", fg='#316879')
label.pack()

img = PhotoImage(file="download.png")
b = Label(image=img)
b.my_img = "download.png"
b.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: у меня так все работает