# Пропадает изображение (PhotoImage ) в виджете Label

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, label, photoimage

Изображение один раз моргает и пропадает.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as fd

root=Tk()
frame=Frame(root,width=300,height=300)
frame.pack()

def img():
        global root,frame
        photo = tk.PhotoImage(file='path')
        h=Label(frame, image=photo)
        h.place(x=0,y=0)
        
        frame.update()
        root.update()
```

Comment: Дайте минимально воспроизводимый код, где встречается данная проблема. Только в таком случае сможем помочь. Иначе, это как пальцем в небо тыкать и, извиняюсь за выражение, пытаться в попу попасть

Comment: На какую помощь вы рассчитываете?

Comment: СДЕЛАЛ.ВСЁ ГОТОВО.

Comment: Что именно сделали?

Comment: Отображение изображения

Comment: Мы за вас безумно рады, но все же, StackOverflow это база знаний вопросов/проблем **и ответов/решений**. =)

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: СДЕЛАЛ.ВСЁ ГОТОВО.

Comment: Тест на человека не пройден)

Comment: Stepan, ВОСПРОИЗВОДИМЫЙ - это когда копируешь ваш пример, запускаешь его и получаешь проблему о которой вы пишите. Попробуйте скопировать и запустить ваш пример в каком-нибудь вновь созданном каталоге.

Comment: Дубликат вопроса: [Не отображается изображение в Label](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/767818/1365)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Жаль, но вы так и не предоставили минимальный воспроизводимый пример. 
Я не знаю, что вы делаете или будите делать в вашем коде, но на сейчас проблема в том, что переменная `photo` удаляется сборщиком мусора после выхода из функции `img()`. Вам надо как-то продлить срок жизни этой переменной.

Попробуйте так:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as fd


root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root, width=500, height=500)
frame.pack()
photo = None                                          # +++

def img():
#        global root, frame, photo                    
        global photo                                  # +++
        photo = tk.PhotoImage(file='lena2.png')
        h = tk.Label(frame, image=photo)
        h.place(x=0, y=0)
        
#        frame.update()
#        root.update()
       

img()
root.mainloop()
```

---

или так:

```
from tkinter import *


class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Window()
    main.geometry("500x500")
    main.resizable(height=False, width=False)
    main.title("Title lena2.png")
    
    bg_img = PhotoImage(file = "lena2.png")
    limg = Label(main, i=bg_img)
    limg.pack()
    
    main.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**lena2.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Вам надо посмотреть в сторону ООП.

Comment: (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist

Comment: @Stepan я не знаю что вы написали в комментарии. Чтобы проверить мои примеры - скопируйте их и запустите у себя. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour . Если у вас есть другие вопросы - задайте новый вопрос.