# Как вывести изображение в новое окно, создаваемое приложением?

Tags: python

Все примеры в Интернете вывода картинки в окно рассматривают вывод в главное окно, а не в дополнительное (новое, которое создается при работе приложения по кнопке). Пробовал различные варианты (Label, Canvas и прочее), но в то время, как в новом окне все текстовые элементы и кнопки благополучно размещаются и показываются, попытка вывода картинки в это новое окно оканчивается ошибкой (отсутствие картинки где-то там глубоко в Tkinter). Если же указать вместо объекта (дополнительное окно, eb=tkinter.Tk()), создаваемое в функции, вызываемой кнопкой приложения, просто г л а в н о е окно (root=tkinter.Tk()) приложения, то картинка благополучно выводится в это главное окно, а это не то, что мне надо. Такое впечатление, что Label, Canvas и прочее обращаются к главному окну, что совершенно непонятно. Не подскажете ли в чем здесь дело?

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767818/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-label-python3-tkinter

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не отображается изображение в Label](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767818/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-label)