# Python Tkinter, PIL. У меня пропадает изображение при открытии нового

Tags: python, tkinter, pil

Я делаю приложение, которое будет показывать изображения.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
window = Tk()
tabControl = Notebook(window)
def getsize(event=False):
    scrollCanvas.configure(width=int(window.winfo_screenwidth())-100, height=int(window.winfo_screenheight())-100, scrollregion=scrollCanvas.bbox(ALL))
def open(filepath, name="Изображение", event=False):
    global PILImage, image, tab, scrollCanvas
    tab = Frame(tabControl)
    tabControl.add(tab, text=name)
    scrollCanvas = Canvas(tab)
    scrollCanvas.place(x=0,y=0)
    PILImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(os.path.abspath(filepath)))
    scrollCanvas.create_image(0, 0, image=PILImage, anchor=NW)
    x_scroll = Scrollbar(tab, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=scrollCanvas.xview)
    x_scroll.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)
    y_scroll = Scrollbar(tab, orient=VERTICAL, command=scrollCanvas.yview)
    y_scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    scrollCanvas.configure(xscrollcommand=x_scroll.set)
    scrollCanvas.configure(yscrollcommand=y_scroll.set)
    window.bind("<Configure>", VarImage.getsize)
    tab.bind("<MouseWheel>", lambda event: scrollCanvas.yview_scroll(-1*(event.delta/120), "units"))
    tabControl.pack(anchor=NW)
window.bind("<Control-n>", open("файл"))
window.mainloop()
```

После создания 2й вкладки изображение с первой пропадает. Как оставить изображение на всех вкладках. (их может быть большое количество, поэтому вариант с отдельной переменной на каждое изобрадение не пойдёт).

Comment: Храните в глобальной переменной список всех открытых изображений. Сейчас сборщик мусора думает, что после того как вы передали изображение в canvas.create_image, оно больше не нужно и уничтожает объект. Связанный вопрос: [Не отображается изображение в Label](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/767818/1365)

Comment: Я вообще всё глобальным сделал. Пока я 2-е изображение не открываю, оно работает. Может список открытых изображений в файле сделать?

Comment: Значит у вас одновременно глобально хранится только одно изображение. Открываете новое - старое в глобальной переменной перезатирается, сборщик мусора его удаляет. Нужно именно все хранить, например в списке, а не только последнее.

Comment: понятно, спасибо. я сделаю tmp файл

Comment: Не знаю, что вы в файле собрались хранить. Нужен просто глобальный список. Добавляете каждое созданное PILImage в него, и все, больше ничего не будет пропадать.

Comment: Не пойму о чём Вы говорите. Я новичок в Python. Можно пример пожалуйста?

Comment: Создаете на верхнем уровне (снаружи всех функций) список `images = []`. После того как создаете PILImage, добавляете его в этот список: `PILImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(os.path.abspath(filepath)))`, потом `images.append(PILImage)`, потом уже прикрепляете его к холсту.

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё получилось.