# Python tkinter gui. При вызове нескольких изображений показывает только последнее

Tags: python, tkinter, gui

Пытаюсь создать симулятор игральных костей с имитацией броска. Программа в целом работает, за исключением того, что из двух запланированных кубиков отображается только последний, указанный в коде. Т.е. функция roll, в которой указаны команды на создание двух изображений кубиков, выводит на экран только последнее.

```py
from tkinter import *
import random, time

def sides():
    global side
    d1 = PhotoImage(file=('d1.png'))
    d2 = PhotoImage(file=('d2.png'))
    d3 = PhotoImage(file=('d3.png'))
    d4 = PhotoImage(file=('d4.png'))
    d5 = PhotoImage(file=('d5.png'))
    d6 = PhotoImage(file=('d6.png'))
    side = random.choice([d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6])
    return side

def button():
    throw.config(state='active')
    
def roll():
    global dice_l, dice_r
    throw.config(state='disabled')
    for i in range(15):
        dice_l = canvas.create_image(270,250,image=sides())
        dice_r = canvas.create_image(530,250,image=sides())
        window.update()
        time.sleep(0.1)
    button()

window = Tk()
window.title('Dice')
window.resizable(height=False, width=False)
window.iconphoto(True, PhotoImage(file=('ikonka.png')))

canvas = Canvas(window, width=800, height=500)
canvas.pack()

bgrd = PhotoImage(file=('stol2.png'))

canvas.create_image(400,250,image=bgrd)

throw = Button(window, text='ROLL', command=roll)
throw.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.9, anchor=S)

roll()

window.mainloop()
```

Изначально пробовал делать через Label с указанием места размещения меток с привязкой к ним кубиков в теле программы, ссылаясь на них в функции roll. Но прозрачность пнг-изображений в таком случае выключалась, и вокруг кубиков появлялся серый фон, потому и перешёл на canvas.

Так-то я только начал питон изучать, и где-то на начальном уровне сейчас, и потому возможно не вижу очевидного. Есть ли какое-то решение данной проблемы?

Comment: Сделайте список и добавляйте каждый созданный PhotoImage в него, чтобы сборщик мусора их не удалял.

Comment: @insolor, в принципе сработало, оба кубика теперь отображаются. Но я вывел команду принта списка, и получается, что он сохраняет каждую итерацию для каждого из двух кубиков каждый раз, как срабатывает функция roll. И получается изображения кубиков как-бы наслаиваются одно на другое, никуда не исчезая. Если что, то я добавил `list.append(side)` в функцию sides перед ретурном

Comment: Ну загрузите изображения один раз в список при старте (а не каждый раз при бросании), потом просто из этого списка доставайте и отображайте.

Comment: @insolor Не знаю, наверное я что-то не то или не так делаю. Можете подробнее указать, что куда и как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы сборщик мусора не удалял изображения, объекты `PhotoImage` нужно после создания куда-то сохранять (если одно - просто в глобальную переменную, если их много - то например в список). См. вопрос: [Не отображается изображение в Label](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/767818/1365).

Чтобы новые изображения не создавались каждый раз при вызове `roll`, нужно изображения один раз загрузить при старте программы, потом только выбирать одно из них из списка:

```
sides_images = []


def load_images():
    for name in ('d1.png', 'd2.png', 'd3.png', 'd4.png', 'd5.png', 'd6.png'):
        sides_images.append(PhotoImage(file=name))


# Загружаем изображения при старте
load_images()


def sides():
    # Не грузим изображения заново,
    # просто выбираем случайное изображение из ранее загруженных
    side = random.choice(sides_images)  
    return side
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось сделать, как Вы сказали.                                                                                              
Но и я методом тыка сделал немного по-своему. Вместо функции `sides` сделал две идентичные `sides_l` и `sides_r`, и ссылки на них в `roll`е соответственно кубикам. Осталось теперь придумать, как прикрутить к ним числа, соответствующие выпадающим картинкам, но то такое.

Comment: @DimUA не понятно зачем две идентичные функции нужны? Просто одну и ту же вызывайте.

Comment: в этом и заключалась вся проблема. Если `dice_l` и `dice_r` в `roll` е ссылаются на одну и ту же функцию, то отображается всего один кубик. Ваш вариант тоже рабочий, но наслоение сторон кубиков всё равно происходит, хотя и всего в количестве шести штук, каждый раз сбрасываясь

Comment: @DimUA нужно смотреть что у вас в этих функциях, так не понятно, зачем еще один набор картинок нужен. По идее должно работать с одним набором.

Comment: Ну вот код из самого вопроса так и работает. Один набор картинок, две ссылки на него, а отображает только по одной из них. Была бы возможность прикрепить картинки, прикрепил бы, чтобы потестить

Comment: Понятно, получается нельзя один PhotoImage в двух виджетах использовать одновременно