# Почему в цикле не показываются изображения PIL?

Tags: python, tkinter, pil

Делаю программу где есть цикл, который по списку по очереди выводит все изображения на экран.
Вот код:

```
imgs = ["images/bt.gif", "images/p9.gif", "images/12.gif"]

photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(imgs[1]), "rb") 
Button(image=photo).pack()
```

Это был код только без цикла. И результат такой:
[image: Результат вывода без цикла]

Сейчас код с циклом:

```
imgs = ["images/bt.gif", "images/p9.gif", "images/12.gif"]

for img in imgs:
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(img), "rb") 
    Button(image=photo).pack()
```

И такой результат:
[image: Результат с циклом]

Тоесть выводится только обводка кнопки, хотя мне нужно, чтобы изображения тоже выводились.
Из за чего это может быть?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Python tkinter gui. При вызове нескольких изображений показывает только последнее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1490201/python-tkinter-gui-%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5)

Comment: Вкратце: объекты PhotoImage нужно сохранять куда-то (в глобальную переменную, в глобальный список, еще куда-то), чтобы их не удалял сборщик мусора.

Comment: Также, см. [Не отображается изображение в Label](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/767818/1365)