# Точка вместо картинки

Tags: python, tkinter

Вот делаю программу и хочу вывести картинку и вот проблема точка место картинки

Часть кода

```
if name.acc == True:        
     label.destroy()
     btnplay.destroy()
     btnaccount.destroy()
     btnop.destroy()
     imge = PhotoImage('\\Gta 6 alfa\\x64\\Data\\Load.png')
     imageBG = Label(ws, image=imge, background='#212121')
     imageBG.place(x=609, y=304)

     Load = ttk.Progressbar(ws, maximum=100, length=866, value=0)
     Load.place(x=22, y=495)

     Loadingtxt = Label(ws, text='Загрузка...', bg='#212121', foreground="white", font='Verdana 10 normal roman')
     Loadingtxt.pack()

     def progress():
         for i in range(101):
             if 100 == Load['value']:
                os.startfile("\\GTA 6 alfa\\x64\\Data\\untro.avi")
             Load['value'] += 1
             sleep(.5)
            
    Thread(target=progress).start()
```

Comment: проблему не решит, но в путях лучше не использовать пробелы

Comment: Сохраняйте картинку в глобальную переменную (или, например, в поле объекта), иначе ее уничтожит сборщик мусора. См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/767818/1365