Программа не работает, не знаю что делать. Примечание: Все необходимые библиотеки я загрузил и работают только 2 изображения. Traceback ошибка
def Reklama():
    global panel
    x = random.randint(1,5)
    if x == 1:
        response = requests.get("https://clck.ru/3AA2je")
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(BytesIO(response.content)))
        panel.configure(image=img)
        panel.image = img
    elif x == 2:
        response = requests.get("https://clck.ru/3AA2qR")
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(BytesIO(response.content)))
        panel.configure(image=img)
        panel.image = img
    elif x == 3:
        response = requests.get("https://ltdfoto.ru/images/2024/04/18/-.jpg")
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(BytesIO(response.content)))
        panel.configure(image=img)
        panel.image = img
    elif x == 4:
        response = requests.get("https://clck.ru/3AA3jr")
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(BytesIO(response.content)))
        panel.configure(image=img)
        panel.image = img
    elif x == 5:
        response = requests.get("https://clck.ru/3AA3rV")
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(BytesIO(response.content)))
        panel.configure(image=img)
        panel.image = img
    pass


Информативная ошибка, да..

С большой вероятностью у вас сборщик мусора удаляет изображения. См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/767829/1365. Нужно сохранять все отображаемые изображения, например, в глобальном списке.
