# Глобальная переменная постоянно равна 0 при использовании multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Имеется код

```
len_urls_phone=0
count_parsed_url=0

def add_count_parsined():
    global count_parsed_url
    count_parsed_url+=1
    return count_parsed_url

def make_all(url):
   parsing_phone(url)
   #write_csv(data)

def parsing_phone(url):
   global name_alternative, brand, represented, state, width, height, thickness, ratio_side, weight, surface_use, certificate_resistance, diagonal, display_type, display_subtype, count_pixels_x, count_pixels_y, density_pixels, display_capacitive, multitouch, display_25d_surved_glass, display_brightness, display_protective_glass, forcetouch, display_ogs, display_scratch_resistance, display_oleophobic_lipophobic_coating, display_ltps, display_zero_air_gap, display_triluminos, display_xReality, display_contrast_ratio, always_on_display, processor_model, processor_CPU, processor_count_core, processor_frequency, processor_64_bits, graphics_GPU, ram, antutu, memory, memory_expandable, fingerprint, fingerprint_location, accelerometer, compas, sensor_gravity, gyroscope, sensor_hall, magnetometer, pedometer, sensor_light, sensor_proximity, led_notification, camera_resolution, camera_sensor, camera_sensor_type, camera_opening, video_4K, camera_autofocus, camera_serial_shooting, camera_digital_zoom, camera_exposure_ompensation, camera_face_detection, camera_geographic_tags, camera_hdr_shooting, camera_setting_ISO, camera_manual_focus, camera_optical_stabilization, camera_panoramic_shooting, camera_RAW, camera_scene_mode, camera_selftimer, camera_touch_focus, camera_settings_balance_white, camera_video_slow_motion, camera_video_slow_motion_fps, camera_video_optical_stabilization, camera_frontal_resolution, net_4G, net_4G_frequency, net_3G_frequency, net_2G_frequency, sim_card_count, sim_card_modework, sim_card_type, WIFI_support_standart, WIFI_mode_dualBand, WIFI_Direct, WIFI_Display, WIFI_Hotspot, WIFI_MiMO, bluetooth_version, bluetooth_LE, bluetooth_mode_A2DP, bluetooth_mode_AVRCP, bluetooth_mode_GAP, bluetooth_mode_GAVDP, bluetooth_mode_HDP, bluetooth_mode_HFP, bluetooth_mode_HID, bluetooth_mode_HSP, bluetooth_mode_MAP, bluetooth_mode_OPP, bluetooth_mode_PAN, bluetooth_mode_PBAP_PAB, bluetooth_mode_SPP, satellite_nafigation_AGPS, satellite_nafigation_Beidou, satellite_nafigation_Glonass, satellite_nafigation_GPS, satellite_nafigation_Galileo, usb_charging, usb_host, usb_mass_charger, usb_OTG, usb_type_C, audio_jack, FM_Radio, computer_synchronization, DLNA, infrared_port, NFS, OTA_synchronization, tethering, VoLTE, battery_capacity, battery_type, battery_fast_charging, battery_withdral, operation_system
   global len_urls_phone
   print("Начало парсинга",url)
   time_parsing = time.time()
   r = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': user_agent})
   soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

   # Нахождение и определение ссылки на изображение
   imagening = soup.find("img", "main-photo")["src"]
   name_image = imagening.split("/")[-1]
   print(name_image)
   url_image = "https:" + imagening
   timeParsingImage = time.time()
   # Скачивание изображения
   h = httplib2.Http('.cache')
   response, content = h.request(url_image)
   out = open('../../image/smartphone/' + name_image, 'wb')
   out.write(content)
   out.close()

   timeDownloadImage = time.time() - timeParsingImage
   print("Время загрузки изображения:", timeDownloadImage)
   image_path = "image/smartphone/" + name_image
   print("Путь изображения:", image_path)

   # Блок basics
   basics = soup.find("div", "description", "clear")

   h1Basics = basics.find("h1")

   name = h1Basics.contents[2].strip()
   print("Название телефона:", name)

   mainBlock = soup.find_all("section", "clear")
   mainBlock.remove(mainBlock[-1])  # Удаляем последнюю секцию сравнения

   for block in mainBlock:
      nameBlock = block["id"]
      tableBlock = block.find("div", "table")
      sectionTableBlock = tableBlock.find_all("div", "row")
      for sectionTableBlock in sectionTableBlock:
         nameSection = sectionTableBlock.contents[1].contents[1].contents[0].string.strip()
         dlSection = sectionTableBlock.find("dl")
         parametrs(nameBlock, nameSection, dlSection)


   print("Общее время", time.time() - time_parsing, "Спарсено: ", url, "-", "Время парсинга страницы",time.time() - time_parsing, "Процент",add_count_parsined/len_urls_phone)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time = time.time()
    urls_phone.append("yandex1.ru")
    urls_phone.append("yandex2.ru")
    urls_phone.append("yandex3.ru")
    len_urls_phone=len(urls_phone)
    with Pool(count_processors) as p:
        p.map(make_all, urls_phone)
    print(time.time() - start_time)
    print("Программа завершена")
```

Сначала  использовал global url_phone, она тоже выдавала 0, подумал что модуль multiprocessing удаляет из списка, те ссылки, которые уже обработал, поэтому создал новую переменную и сразу присвоил ей значение в `if __name__ == "__main__":`, но она также выдает 0 в любом методе (например parsing())

Comment: Пожалуйста, понятнее объясните суть вопроса.
На сколько я понял, вам нужна Queue.
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/queue.html

Comment: @MrMorgan у меня нету проблемы с потоками, я просто не могу глобальной переменной присвоить значение. В __name__ = "__main__" я присваиваю значение глобальной переменной, но в других методах, этаже глобальная переменная равна значению по умолчанию. Как так?

Comment: Возможно Вы создаёте свои локальные переменные, заместо глобальных. Попробуйте написать global перед каждым(где global ещё не писалось) использованием данных глобальных переменных

Comment: @MrMorgan я же уже объявил в методе parsing глобальную переменную, которой присвоил значение в if __name__ == "__main__". Почему она все также равно 0?

Comment: @danilshik, в каждом процессе своя глобальная переменная urls_phone, они между собой никак не сообщаются. Вам действительно нужен Queue.

Comment: Вопрос не про процессы. Вопрос был про переменную len_urls_phone. Мне нужно использовать ее в других функциях. А что касательно urls_phone, то там все правильно, в каждый процесс передается 1 ссылка из списка urls_phone

Comment: @danilshik, ну вообще в приведенном коде у вас строка `len_urls_phone=len(urls_phone)` выполняется один раз. При последующем изменении списка `urls_phone` переменная `len_urls_phone` не будет автоматически меняться.

Comment: @insolor так а зачем мне чтобы она менялась. Ладно объясню так, в список последовательно добавляется ссылки для парсинга, в конце добавления мне нужно узнать общее количество ссылок в списке. Суть в том что если я в другой функции объявлю через глобал  список либо переменную len_urls_phone, они мне выдадут 0 (значение, по умолчанию верхнее), а не какое то любое другое значение.

Comment: Почему так происходит? Ведь это и так глобальные переменные в if __name__ == "__main__":   . Если я даже объявлю их в этой части как                                                                            
global urls_phone                                                                                   global  len_urls_phone         
urls_phone.append("https://www.yandex.ru/")        
len_urls_phone=len(urls_phone), то интерпретатор выдаст ошибку SyntaxError: name 'urls_phone' is assigned to before global declaration,

Comment: @danilshik, какая другая функция? как она вызывается? Добавьте в вопрос [минимальный, самодостаточный, воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Код, который у вас в вопросе, таковым примером не является.

Comment: @insolor обновил код, весь скинуть не могу слишком много кода

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Каждый процесс имеет своё независимое адресное пространство. Чтобы данными делиться необходимы явные действия в общем случае. Вот пример, демонстрирующий, что значение, определённое в `__main__` не  видно в дочерних процессах. Видно только значение, доступное при импорте модуля:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import logging
import multiprocessing as mp
import sys

global_var = 'import level'


def log_global_var(i):
    mp.get_logger().info('%d global_var=%s', i, global_var)
    return i*i


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.log_to_stderr().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    #  spawn/fork/forkserver
    start_method = 'spawn' if len(sys.argv) < 2 else sys.argv[1]
    mp.get_logger().info('%s start method', start_method)
    mp.set_start_method(start_method)

    global_var = 'in main'
    with mp.Pool(2) as pool:
        print(pool.map(log_global_var, range(4)))
    mp.get_logger().info('parent global_var=%s', global_var)
```

Пример запуска:

```
$ python3 log_global.py
[INFO/MainProcess] spawn start method
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] 0 global_var=import level
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] 1 global_var=import level
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] 2 global_var=import level
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] 3 global_var=import level
[0, 1, 4, 9]
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] process shutting down
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] process shutting down
[INFO/MainProcess] parent global_var=in main
[INFO/MainProcess] process shutting down
```

Присваивание `global_var = 'in main'` не видно в дочерних процессах, используя `'spawn'` метод запуска процессов.

На системах, где доступен `'fork'` метод (*nix), видно это значение:

```
$ python3 log_global.py fork
[INFO/MainProcess] fork start method
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] 0 global_var=in main
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] 1 global_var=in main
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] 2 global_var=in main
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] 3 global_var=in main
[0, 1, 4, 9]
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] process shutting down
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] process shutting down
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] process exiting with exitcode 0
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] process exiting with exitcode 0
[INFO/MainProcess] parent global_var=in main
[INFO/MainProcess] process shutting down
```

Дочерние процессы видят `global_var = 'in main'` в этом случае.

Чтобы получить значение вне зависимости от способа запуска, можно его наследовать явно:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import logging
import multiprocessing as mp
import sys

global_var = 'import level'


def init(global_var_):  # inherit
    global global_var
    global_var = global_var_


def log_global_var(i):
    mp.get_logger().info('%d global_var=%s', i, global_var)
    return i*i


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.log_to_stderr().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    #  spawn/fork/forkserver
    start_method = 'spawn' if len(sys.argv) < 2 else sys.argv[1]
    mp.get_logger().info('%s start method', start_method)
    mp.set_start_method(start_method)

    global_var = 'in main'
    with mp.Pool(2, initializer=init, initargs=[global_var]) as pool:
        print(pool.map(log_global_var, range(4)))
    mp.get_logger().info('parent global_var=%s', global_var)
```

Пример:

```
python log_global.py 
[INFO/MainProcess] spawn start method
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] 0 global_var=in main
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] 1 global_var=in main
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] 2 global_var=in main
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] 3 global_var=in main
[0, 1, 4, 9]
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] process shutting down
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] process exiting with exitcode 0
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] process shutting down
[INFO/MainProcess] parent global_var=in main
[INFO/MainProcess] process shutting down
```

Обратите внимание `global` объявление внутри функции нужно, только для присваивания. При чтении имя и так доступно. [Использование global в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/767668/23044).

Стоит отметить, что изменения `global_var` в дочерних процессах будут видны только внутри этих процессов. Данные можно передать (один из методов) с помощью явных аргументов (как `i` в примере) и передать данные назад в родительский процесс с помощью возвращаемого значения (`return i*i` в примере). Внутри это реализовано с помощью сериализации соответствующих объектов и пересылки полученных байтов между процессами.