# Не могу задать переменную в tkinter Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Есть код:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.messagebox
import time


n = 0

root = Tk()
root.title("Enter")
root.geometry("450x75")
lab_l = Label(root,text = "Login:")
lab_p = Label(root,text = "Password:")

ent_l = Entry(root)
ent_p = Entry(root)

def enter(event):
    get_l = ent_l.get()
    get_p = ent_p.get()

    if (get_l == ("l")) and (get_p == ("p")):


        lab_err['text'] = ("Please,wait...")
        root.destroy()


    else:
        n += 1
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Wrong Password or Log ',('You have ',n, ' tries left'))
        lab_err['text'] = ("Login or Password is incorrect,please,try again!")


lab_l.grid(row = 0,column=0)
ent_l.grid(row = 0,column=1)
lab_p.grid(row = 1,column=0)
ent_p.grid(row = 1,column=1)

lab_err = Label(root,fg="red")
lab_err.grid(row = 1,column=3,padx=5)

l_w_1 = Label(root,text = '')
l_w_1.grid(row = 2,column=2,pady = 5)
l_w_2 = Label(root,text = '')
l_w_2.grid(row = 2,column=3,pady = 5)
l_w_3 = Label(root,text = '')
l_w_3.grid(row = 2,column=4,pady = 5)

btn = Button(root,bg="grey",text="Try",width="10")
btn.bind("<Button-1>",enter)
btn.grid(row = 2,column=1,pady = 5)
root.mainloop()

root_1 = Tk()

root.mainloop()
```

---

Хочу сделать, чтобы в messagebox отображалось и менялось количество попыток,которое остается.Т.е. после каждого неправильного ввода пароля вылетало окно с

> `('You have ',n, ' tries left')`

Но проблема заключается в том,что я не знаю куда поставить n:ставлю как в коде выдает:

> `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'n' referenced before assignment`

,работает только если назначить n в самом `def` ,но какой смысл если она не будет меняться?

Comment: в начале когда создаешь переменную n перед ней попробуй написать строчку
global n
а потом уже писать
n=0
ну или другое число

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка:

> `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'n' referenced before assignment`
>   означает, что ваша переменная `n` является локальной, что в свою очередь ее нельзя путем сложения присваивать.

В данном коде описывается класс в котором в `def __init__` хранятся данные об окне приложение(`entry, button, Tk`) когда вы в классе прописываете [`self` ( это ссылка на экземпляр класса, т.е. на самого себя.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self/21366809#21366809) вы делаете эту переменную открытую внутри класса т.е. вы можете изменять ее без приписывания [`global`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767668/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-global-%D0%B2-python/767734#767734)

Сам код программы делает следующее при нажатии на кнопку вы вызываете функцию `checked` которая в свою очередь проверяет переменную `number_trying` на то является ли она истинной (т.е. `number_trying > 0` ) после чего проверяет на введенность данных полученные из переменных `entry_password` и `entry_login` (где соответственно если пароль == 1 а логин == admin), если это не так то из переменной `number_trying` вычитаем единицу, и так пока `number_trying` не будет равна `0` в результате чего (если  `number_trying == 0`) вам будет выдано сообщение что попытки закончились

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox

class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.number_trying = 5
        self.entry_login = tk.Entry()
        self.entry_password = tk.Entry()
        self.entry_login.grid()
        self.entry_password.grid()
        button = tk.Button(text='нажми')
        button.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: self.checked())
        button.grid()

    def checked(self):
        if self.number_trying:
            if self.entry_password.get() == '1' and self.entry_login.get() == 'admin':
                self.number_trying = 5
            else:
                tk.messagebox.showinfo('количество попыток', 'осталось {}'.format(self.number_trying))
                self.number_trying -= 1
        else:
            tk.messagebox.showinfo('количество попыток ', 'ваши попытки закончились')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = Main()
    main.mainloop()
```

---

А это исправленный ваш код с использование `global` что делать не особо желательно

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox


def enter(event):
    get_l = ent_l.get()
    get_p = ent_p.get()
    global n

    if get_l == "l" and get_p == "p":
        lab_err['text'] = "Please,wait..."
        root.destroy()

    else:
        n += 1
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Wrong Password or Log ', 'You have ' + str(n) + ' tries left')
        lab_err['text'] = "Login or Password is incorrect, please,try again!"


n = 0
root = Tk()
root.title("Enter")
root.geometry("450x75")
lab_l = Label(root, text="Login:")
lab_p = Label(root, text="Password:")
ent_l = Entry(root)
ent_p = Entry(root)
lab_l.grid(row=0, column=0)
ent_l.grid(row=0, column=1)
lab_p.grid(row=1, column=0)
ent_p.grid(row=1, column=1)

lab_err = Label(root, fg="red")
lab_err.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=5)

l_w_1 = Label(root, text='')
l_w_1.grid(row=2, column=2, pady=5)
l_w_2 = Label(root, text='')
l_w_2.grid(row=2, column=3, pady=5)
l_w_3 = Label(root, text='')
l_w_3.grid(row=2, column=4, pady=5)

btn = Button(root, bg="grey", text="Try", width="10")
btn.bind("<Button-1>", enter)
btn.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=5)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'n' referenced before assignment также выдает

Comment: Вообще ничего не понятно,даже никаких объяснений,просто новый код

Comment: @QqqqSsss добавил описание

Comment: Спасибо,очень помог!