# Почему если не объявить переменную глобальной, выдаст ошибку

Tags: python

Объясните пожалуйста в чём разница и как работает в данном примере локальная и глобальная переменная

```
>>> x = 10
>>> def foobar():
...     global x
...     print(x)
...     x += 1
>>> foobar()
10
```

Comment: Да связь есть. Спасибо

Comment: связанный вопрос [Использование global в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/767668/23044)