# Как работает "global" в Python?

Tags: python

скажите пожалуйста как работает зарезервированное слово "global" в Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При создании новой переменной в функции, они действуют только в пределе функции. Чтобы изменять глобальные переменные внутри функции, определите их с помощью global. (Пример у ответа выше)

Answer (score 3):

Когда внутри функции создаются новые переменные, они имеют локальную область видимости. То есть такие переменные определены только в пределах тела функции, и они уничтожаются, когда функция возвращает управление вызывающей программе. Чтобы иметь возможность изменять глобальные переменные внутри функции, эти переменные следует определить в теле функции с помощью инструкции global

```
count = 0
...
def foo():
    global count
    count += 1  # Изменяет значение глобальной переменной count
```

Comment: Как правильно использовать "global"

Comment: @Алексей, правильнее будет его не использовать вообще. Смотрите [замечание в конце данного ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/767734/211923)

Comment: @MaxU, не сказал бы. Иногда без global сложно обойтись. В каких-то сложных функциях, особенно с циклами если.

Comment: Большое спасибо