# Управление данными функций

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Почему в последнем принте x = 2?

```
def func_outer():
    x = 2
    print('x равно', x)
    def func_inner():
        global x
        x = 5
        print (x)
    func_inner()
    print('Локальное x сменилось на', x)
func_outer()
```

Comment: `global x` -> `nonlocal x` :)

Comment: Это я знаю. Я хочу понять почему именно при global работает так. И я не совсем полностью понимаю как работает nonlocal, объясните пожалуйста тоже, если не сложно.

Comment: Как я понимаю после определения во вложенной функции x должен быть равен 5 и за пределами вложенной функции. Или же x будет равен 5 только в теле второй функции и всех вложенных в неё? Я правильно понял?

Comment: Я понял как они работают.

Comment: О, вы молодец, что разобрались :) Напишите в ответе об этом ;)

Answer (score 1):

К примеру у вас имеется две функции, одна из которых вложенная во вторую. Если вы хотите во второй функции получить значение переменной из первой функции, то во второй функции необходимо указать nonlocal к переменной, которую необходимо передать. x(1) – первая функция, x(2). Предположим, что x(1) у нас будет равен 5. Мы указали nonlocal x(2), таким образом, x(1) у нас будет равен 5 во второй функции ровно до того момента, пока мы не перезапишем эту переменную. Так же будет если мы создадим ещё одну вложенную функцию, в которую так же хотим передать эту переменную.

```
def func_outer(): 
    x = 2
    print('x равно', x)
    def func_inner(): 

        nonlocal x
        print (x)
        x = 5
        print (x)

        def func_three():

            nonlocal x
            print ('До изменения третьей', x)
            x = 9
            print('Чекаю третью после изменения', x)
        func_three()

    func_inner()
    print('Локальное x сменилось на', x)
func_outer()
```

Что касается global. Тут похожая ситуация. Но в этом случае мы можем передать в функцию или класс, значение переменной вне тела класса или функции.

```
global x
x = 2
def func_outer(): 
    #x = 2
    print('x равно', x)
    def func_inner(x): 

        #nonlocal x
        print (x)
        x = 5
        print (x)

        def func_three(x):

            #nonlocal x
            print ('До изменения третьей', x)
            x = 9
            print('Чекаю третью после изменения', x)
        func_three(x)

    func_inner(x)
    print('Локальное x сменилось на', x)
func_outer()
```

Comment: `global` не используется вне функций. Использовать его в методах, мне кажется, тоже такая себе затея.

Comment: Не понял. А зачем тогда его использовать? Разве не в этом смысл функции global?

Comment: Чтобы включить объект из `globals()` в пространство имен функции, и использовать его. Исключает ситуацию конфликта имён.

Comment: Вот ссылки [Оф1](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement), [Оф2](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value), [на ru SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/767668/258244).