# Передача переменной из одной функции в другую

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как получить переменную `name` как глобальную?

```py
import random
fruits = ('яблоко', 'абрикос', 'авокадо', 'банан', 'кокос', 'инжир')           
def  fruitName(): 
   rand = random.randint(0,6)
   name = fruits[rand]
print(name)
```

Понимаю, что вопрос достаточно глупой, но я только начала изучение программирования.

Comment: совет начинающему программисту: всегда пишите такие функции, которые возвращают результат при помощи `return ...` и никогда не используйте глобальные переменные (пока точно не будете знать что вы делаете) ;) PS с опытом прийдет понимание когда данные правила можно нарушать...

Comment: [Использование global в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767668) - советую внимательно прочитать ответы...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого Вы можете воспользоваться инструкцией `global`, например:

```py
global name
name = fruits[rand]
```

---

**Возьмите на заметку!**
Использовать глобальные переменные - ужасное архитектурное решение.
Если есть возможность избегать их - это обязательно нужно сделать.

Лучше сделать так:

```py
import random


def get_rand_fruit(fruits: list) -> str: 
    rand_fruit = random.choice(fruits)
    return rand_fruit


fruits = ('яблоко', 'абрикос', 'авокадо', 'банан', 'кокос', 'инжир')

name = get_rand_fruit(fruits)
print(name)
```

Comment: считаю использование глобальных переменных - почти "абсолютным" злом ;)

Comment: @MaxU Это просто ужасно, полностью с Вами согласен. Не встречал ещё ни одного случая, когда бы они пригодились мне. Пожалуй, напишу это в P. S.

Comment: @MaxU разве return имеет какой-то смысл в самом исполняемом файле. Я имею ввиду что в если мы будем писать саму функцию в консоле, то тогда она нам будет возвращать что-либо, но если мы обратимся к ней в файле .py то она нам ничего не возвратит.  Или может я не права?. И почему же вы считаете глобальные переменные 'абсолютным злом'? Извините если я туплю. Я девушка, мне простительно)))))))))

Comment: @ShadowDevil Функция является функцией где бы она не находилась и как бы не вызывалась. Если Вы не указываете `return` - то по умолчанию возвращается `None`. Но это нехорошо. Лучше, чтобы функция возвращала какое-то сгенерированное значение и Вы его присваивали нужной переменной.

Comment: @ShadowDevil Я привёл хороший пример в ответ.

Comment: @ShadowDevil, [почему использование глобальных переменных - зло](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)

Comment: @nomnoms12 Похоже я неправильно задала вопрос. Правильный вопрос должен выглядеть так: Как получить переменную от функциию. За функцию random.choice() Большое спасибо! Я не знала

Comment: @ShadowDevil С помощью `return` в функции. Я обновил пример, явно присвоив результат функции переменной `name`.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Я знаю что благодарить в комментариях не желательно, но благодаря вам я узнала нечто новое в Python'е. Спасибо:3. В дальнейшем надеюсь таких глупых вопросов у меня не возникнет)

Comment: @MaxU Также спасибо (см предыдущей комментарий вас тоже касается)

Comment: @ShadowDevil, глупых вопросов не бывает! ;) На SO часто попадаются плохие вопросы, в которых не хватает информации, чтобы дать адекватный ответ. Ваш вопрос понятный, самодостаточный и с примером кода - именно на такие вопросы приятно давать ответы. (Поэтому +1 от меня ;)

Comment: @ShadowDevil, __nomnoms12__ был первым, давшим правильный ответ, поэтому будет справедливо если вы отметите __его__ ответ как верный ;)

Comment: @MaxU Если человек получил верный ответ и узнал для себя что-то новое, то мы выполнили свою миссию. Мне не принципиально, чей ответ будет отмечен как верный :)

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае стоит воспользоваться готовой функцией [random.choice()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) вместо написания своей функции:

```
import random

fruits = ('яблоко', 'абрикос', 'авокадо', 'банан', 'кокос', 'инжир')
```

---

**примеры:**

```
In [105]: random.choice(fruits)
Out[105]: 'кокос'

In [106]: random.choice(fruits)
Out[106]: 'авокадо'

In [107]: random.choice(fruits)
Out[107]: 'инжир'
```

Answer (score 1):

Прислушайтесь к советам по поводу использования глобальных переменных
Обратите внимание на аргументы метода randint - обе границы инклюзивны.

```
import random
fruits = ('яблоко', 'абрикос', 'авокадо', 'банан', 'кокос', 'инжир')           

def  fruitName(fruits: list): 
    rand = random.randint(0,5) # <--- здесь
    name = fruits[rand]
    return name

print(fruitName(fruits))
```